# Read each json object as single row in Dataframe using Pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below JSON file

```
{"name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York"}
{"name":"Henry", "age":41, "city":"Boston"}
{"name":"Dave", "age":26, "city":"New York"}
```

So from this I need to read each json line as a single row along with the Dataframe.

**Below is the expected output:**

[image]

I've tried with the below code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName('Read Json') \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format('json').load('sample_json')
df.show()
```

But I'm only able to get the below output:

[image]

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file as `json` then Use **`to_json`** function to create `json_column`.

**`1.Using to_json function:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *    
spark.read.json("sample.json").\
withColumn("Json_column",to_json(struct(col("age"),col('city'),col('name')))).\
show(10,False)
#+---+--------+-----+------------------------------------------+
#|age|city    |name |Json_column                               |
#+---+--------+-----+------------------------------------------+
#|31 |New York|John |{"age":31,"city":"New York","name":"John"}|
#|41 |Boston  |Henry|{"age":41,"city":"Boston","name":"Henry"} |
#|26 |New York|Dave |{"age":26,"city":"New York","name":"Dave"}|
#+---+--------+-----+------------------------------------------+

#or more dynamic way
df=spark.read.json("sample.json")
df.withColumn("Json_column",to_json(struct([col(c) for c in df.columns]))).show(10,False)
#+---+--------+-----+------------------------------------------+
#|age|city    |name |Json_column                               |
#+---+--------+-----+------------------------------------------+
#|31 |New York|John |{"age":31,"city":"New York","name":"John"}|
#|41 |Boston  |Henry|{"age":41,"city":"Boston","name":"Henry"} |
#|26 |New York|Dave |{"age":26,"city":"New York","name":"Dave"}|
#+---+--------+-----+------------------------------------------+
```

---

**`2.Other approach using get_json_object function:`**

Read the **json** file as **text** then create `name,age,city` columns by extracting from `json object`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
spark.read.text("sample.json").\
withColumn("name",get_json_object(col("value"),"$.name")).\
withColumn("city",get_json_object(col("value"),"$.city")).\
withColumn("age",get_json_object(col("value"),"$.age")).\
withColumnRenamed("value","Json_column").\
select("age","city","name","Json_column").\
show(10,False)
#+---+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------+
#|age|city    |name |Json_column                                 |
#+---+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------+
#|31 |New York|John |{"name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York"}|
#|41 |Boston  |Henry|{"name":"Henry", "age":41, "city":"Boston"} |
#|26 |New York|Dave |{"name":"Dave", "age":26, "city":"New York"}|
#+---+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: or else you can also use list comprehension `to_json(struct([df[col] for col in df.columns]))`

Comment: @BeardAspirant, Yep.. Added that part too!